# How to "add" the history of a previous git repo to a new one?

Tags: git, github, git-rewrite-history

So, I had this repo on a GitHub account, and also stored in local on the PC. At a certain point I deleted the account and made a new one. I created a blank repo on the new one, picked the local files from the old repo (minus the .git folder) and put them in the new repo and published it. From then on I continued the development on the new acc, making commits etc.. Now, considering that I still am in possess of the original local files of the repo that was in the older account, is there a way to "rewrite" the git history of the new repo to add the commits from the old one (and possibly also add the eventual branches, pull requests etc.)? I guess this is something to be done with `git rebase` but I don't know precisely what to do.

I searched online, found something related but not specifically for this scenario and I'm afraid that I'll do a mess. What's the right way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

Consider I have a github repo containing the *OLD* repo on *main* branch.

I managed to put the old and the new repo together by following these steps:

1. Add a branch to the *OLD* repo called "old-repo-new-branch";
2. In the newly created branch, push the *NEW* repo;
3. Run this command `git rebase --onto IdOfLastCommitInMainBranch IdOfFirstCommitInNewBranch old-repo-new-branch` *(swap IdOfLastCommitInMainBranch and IdOfFirstCommitInNewBranch with the relative ids);*
4. It rebased and put together the 2 repos in the old-repo-new-branch branch, with their commit histories, but then when syncing (pull & push) with the remote I got this new error: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`;
5. I googled it up and solved by doing `git pull origin old-repo-new-branch --allow-unrelated-histories` and then pushing;

Now the issue is that the commit in the "middle" of the 2 histories (old and new) looks to not have a parent (it should have the penultimate *OLD* repo commit as parent). In fact when I look it up the diff on github.com or GitHub Desktop, it has all the files in the repo with a green "+". Instead it should show the modifies in respect to the previous commit.

**FINAL UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

I was doing a mess cause I was rebasing while the repo was already pushed to github. I followed @etfshift0 answer and used:
`git rebase --onto id-of-last-commit-to-keep-from-old-repo id-of-first-commit-in-new-repo branch-of-new-repo`
while having the newRepo branch only locally, and then published it. Solved!

Comment: @topsail Yes. I also mention it 2 sentences later :). EDIT: When I say "I still am in possess of the original local files", I also mean the og .git folder

Comment: I think you rebased in the wrong direction.... It should be rebasing the branch from the _new_ repo onto the _old_ repo. So, `git rebase --onto old-branch id-of-fist-commit-in-new-branch new-branch`. Check my answer carefully.

Comment: @eftshift0 Sorry it was a typo, but I actually did it like you said.

Comment: Ok.... If that is the case, then on the rebased branch, it looks as if you had done all that work from the old branch since you started developing.... So history looks good, right? If that is the case, you have to _replace_ the branch on the new repo, right? That will require a force-push.

Comment: History didn't really look good, but I think I found the issue.. I was doing the rebase on public branches! Which is what was causing the mess :/. I did it without remotes and only pushing it after, and now looks to be solved. Thank you! Your answer really opened up the way to the final solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done *easily* if the tree of the first commit of the **new** repo is exactly like the tree of a given commit from the *old* repo. If you can get a commit from the old repo that has a tree that is *exactly* the same as the tree of the first commit of the new repo, then you can use a script I developed for exactly this purpose: https://github.com/eantoranz/git-replay

You can use it in a repo that can *see* the old and the new history (that is a separate question if you don't know how to do that).

If the trees are not *the same* then you need to find the commit from the old repo that has a tree that best resembles the tree in the first commit of the new repo... Let's call that commit from the old repo `X`. Then you can do this:

```
git rebase --onto X id-of-first-commit-in-new-repo the-branch-of-the-new-repo
```

That should place all commits after the first commit from the new repo on top of the old branch.

I would advice to create a temporary branch at the same place of the new repo branch and play with it until you get the results you want so not to mess up the *real* branch.

Assumption: I am assuming that the *first* commit of the *new* repo was just copying the files from the old repo and committing without adding any changes.

Comment: I tried using the `git rebase` command, anyway I'm getting an error. I replaced `X` with the id of the last commit of the old repo,  `id-of-first...` with the id of the first commit of the new repo, and `the-branch...` with the branch name. Anyway, it tells me that `id-of-first...` is "not a valid upstream". Not really sure what to do as I'm not very used with command line git.

Comment: Paste the full command you used as a comment

Comment: Ok sorry I misread your answer. I managed to fully merge the old and new repos and keep histories of both. The commit that was the 1st of the new, took the place of the one that was the last of the old. Now the only issue is, that that one commit does not show the modifies in respect to the penultimate commit of the old one. It shows all files as they've all been added in that commit. It's a bit of a twisted concept Idk if I explained it good enough

Comment: To be clearer: the commit that now acts as a "divider" between the old commits and the new commits, has no parent

Comment: I could not understand.... Perhaps you need to add an _update_ (with enough details.... including the command you ran) to the original question.....

Comment: Ok thanks. I updated, I hope it's clearer now